# How to render a component just after an async method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-router-dom

I have a custom route that renders a page or redirects the user to the login page based on if the user logged in or not.

```
const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getAuth = async () => {
            const res = await auth.isAuthenticated();
            setIsAuthenticated(() => res);
        };
        getAuth()
    }, [auth]);

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={() => {
                return isAuthenticated ? (
                    <>{children}</>
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to="/login" />
                );
            }}
        ></Route>
    );
};
```

As you see inside `useEffect` I run an async method. The problem is that whenever the component wants to mount, the default value of `isAuthenticated` will be used and redirects the user to the login page. I'm a little confused about how to handle this situation. I don't want the component to be rendered when the async method is not completely run.

Comment: You simply have to add a check on whether the user is already authenticated or not: `getAuth()` becomes `if (!isAuthenticated) getAuth()` (and you have to add `isAuthenticated` among the `useEffect()` dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

i believe it will process all your code before sending html to client's browser.

Comment: I only care about the isAuthenticated value when the return method of the component wants to run.

Comment: await auth.isAuthenticated(); <<< it's awaited as i understant, so don't worry, it will run pseudo-synchronously. EDIT: AAH i understand your question now. NO, you can't guarantee that. Use await auth.isAuthenticated() or await auth.isAuthenticated().Wait(); to run in sync mode